# Dynamic Arguments in Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

In Javascript, you are supposed to be able to access the arguments passed to a function via the arguments key word.  This should alert "tony" and "magoo" but instead it alerts "undefined" - why?

```
function myFunction(){
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        alert(arguments[i].value);
    }
}

myFunction("tony", "Magoo");
```

Comment: Note it's not a keyword, strictly speaking. It's basically just a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `arguments[i]`, without `.value`.

The [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object is an array-like object, all arguments can be accessed through numeric indices.

Comment: Great answer.  Is there a special name for this characteristic of the language

Comment: @dublintech There's no special name. It's just a variable, defined on every function instance. If you're looking for even more details: This is the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x10.6) for the arguments.